# $ \prod_{k=0}^\infty \prod_{j=1}^q ( 1- \chi(j) z/(kq+j) ) = (1-z) \prod_{k=2}^\infty ( 1 - \chi(k) z/k) $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-character

Let $\chi$ be a primitive non-principal Dirichlet character with conductor $q>1$.
The following equation

$$ \prod_{k=0}^\infty\prod_{j=1}^q \biggl( 1- \chi(j) \frac{z}{kq+j} \biggr) = (1-z) \prod_{k=2}^\infty \biggl( 1 - \chi(k) \frac{z}{k} \biggr) $$

appears as (3.6) in https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aam.2018.05.003. How does one go about proving this identity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is $q$-periodic then $$\prod_{k=0}^\infty\prod_{j=1}^q \biggl( 1- f(j) \frac{z}{kq+j} \biggr)=\prod_{k=0}^\infty\prod_{j=1}^q \biggl( 1- f(kq+j) \frac{z}{kq+j} \biggr)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty \biggl( 1- f(n) \frac{z}{n} \biggr)$$
It remains to show it converges (locally uniformly, thus to an entire function) iff $f$ has zero mean, by taking the $\log$ and using that for $|z|<N$, $$\sum_{n>2 N}  \log(1-f(n) \frac{z}n)=-\sum_{n>2N} (f(n) \frac{z}{n}+O(\frac{z^2}{n^2}))$$ converges uniformly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It's really the second equality in the first displayed equation that I'm stuck on. Is there an identity or property you use to evaluate the finite product?

Comment: No. Just letting $n=kq+j$.